# Drag the parent node instead of the drag handle itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Below is a list of items. Each item has a `.drag-handle` which is intended to reorder items by dragging the whole `.drag-group` and switch it with another. The reordering is working fine but only the handle is dragged, I want the entire `.drag-group` to be dragged instead.

```js
function handleDragged(e) {
    let target = e.target.closest('.drag-group');
    target.classList.add('dragging');
    let dropTarget =
        document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) === null
            ? target
            : document
                    .elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)
                    .closest('.drag-group');

    if (dropTarget && target.parentNode === dropTarget.parentNode) {
        dropTarget =
            dropTarget !== target.nextSibling
                ? dropTarget
                : dropTarget.nextSibling;
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(target, dropTarget);
    }
}

function handleDropped(e) {
    e.target.closest('.drag-group').classList.remove('dragging');
}

function onLoad() {
    let dragHandles = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-handle');
    Array.prototype.map.call(dragHandles, (handle) => {
        handle.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        handle.ondrag = handleDragged;
        handle.ondragend = handleDropped;
    });
}

onLoad();
```

```css
 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.draggable {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #5c636a;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: auto;
    flex-grow:1;
}

.dragging {
    cursor: grabbing;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.drag-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.drag-handle {
    cursor: grab;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
```

```html
 

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="drag-group">
        <span class="drag-handle">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="draggable">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-group">
        <span class="drag-handle">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="draggable">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-group">
        <span class="drag-handle">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"
                ></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="draggable">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The desired effect should be similar to the below except for I want the dragged item to stop being visible after being dragged.

[image: effect]

I was expecting the dragged item to become invisible by using:

```
.dragging {
    cursor: grabbing;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

but for some reason it's not working.